# Windows server 2008 R2 can ping internet but not browse

Tags: networking, internet-explorer, windows-server-2008-r2

Good evening everyone.  I have a windows 2008 R2 server that is a terminal server and it will ping internet IP's and DNS names but I cant browse to the site through IE or Chrome.  What Ive tried is:

1. Double checked IP settings
2. Disabled Firewall
3. NSlookup was successful
4. Tracert completed just fine
5. netsh winsock reset ran and still didnt fix
6. Going through Barracuda unchecked

I dunno what to do next

Comment: Probably a service is consuming the interface. Especially if there are other services installed and running. Did you try stopping running services? You could also ping a site like Google, obtain the IP and try to open the page using that IP, instead of the dns name. See if it works. You could also telnet to google and see if port 80 can be used to access outside (telnet www.google.com 80). You may have to enable the feature to use telnet. Make sure to disable it once used.

Comment: I didn't check services but I did try to get to Google through the IP and it still didn't work.  I did however just run netsh int ip reset and now I'm driving to work because I want communicate to it anymore....

Comment: So I reloaded the network settings and turned on the DHCP and it works with a different IP.  I put it back to static and no browser but can still pint out using ip or dns

Comment: Did you set your default gateway correctly? And the IP Address reservations if any? If a DHCP offered IP can access the network, you can identify the DNS settings and Default gateway.

Comment: Yea I ran ipconfig /all with both IP's and they have the same information except for the IP.  I checked the DHCP Server and the reservation is still set correctly.

Comment: Can you check your chrome or IE proxy settings? also make to telnet google.com on port 80 and see if it works

Comment: All proxy boxes are empty.  I will try telnet in the morning

Comment: Something else weird I noticed this morning.  I can browse to almost everything on my network except my primary DNS server.  I cant get to it at all from only this server.  I can ping it by IP and DNS name just fine but Windows will not browse to it.